# reporting tool in C

Tags: c

Is there a reporting tool in C? like jasper report in java.

Comment: You are going 0 for 8 on accepted answers. Bad Shweta, Bad Shweta!

Comment: Byron Whitlock means that you should accept an answer if you are satisfied. It is not required, but it's nice to those that answer your question. (And you can use the upvote option too).

Comment: sorry didnt know the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Doxygen.

Personally I'm not a fan as you create ugly comments full of pseudo html tags, that reduce the code's readability, to produce pretty documents.  Many organisations use it and it can be made to work OK with the right guidelines.